# Minimax tic-tac-toe algorithm implementation problems

Tags: python, micropython

I've got problems with implementing minimax algorithm for my tic-tac-toe game.

It's best if you run the code on your computers. If you want to test it by yourself use: https://wokwi.com/projects/365185972838894593

I was using tutorial https://editor.p5js.org/codingtrain/sketches/0zyUhZdJD

I've tried other tutorials, run code in other compilers and nothing works. I'd be happy if you could fix the algorithm

Comment: It's best if you include a [mre] directly in the question.

Comment: Which problems do you have with the algorithm exactly?

Comment: computer calculates its move for ever, but without runtime error or max depth of recursion error

Comment: Why should it not calculate forever?

Comment: Try it yourself, just simulate. The computer doesn't make any move

Comment: Maybe your program does not execute any code where the computer makes a move.

Comment: It does. I tested simple possibilities